# ftplib.error_perm: 550 when trying to change directory

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to work with provided CSV files on an FTP.
I can log onto the FTP Server and when I:

```
ftp = FTP(server);
ftp.login(user = 'user', passwd = '***');
print(ftp.dir());
```

it works fine.
But I can't change the directory by  `ftp.cwd('/CSV')`
It comes up with a permission error. Even though I'm
already logged in. What's the problem?

I've even tried:

```
ftp = FTP(server);
ftp.login(user = 'user', passwd = '***');
ftp.cwd('/CSV');
ftp.login(user = 'user', passwd = '***');
```

Is it possible to create a server connection with the path directly, like so:
`server = server/CSV/Folder`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the leading slash:

```
ftp.cwd('CSV');
```

It's possible that your account is not chrooted, so the desired path is like `/user/home/CSV`, not `/CSV`. Or your FTP server does not support absolute paths with `CWD` command.